# How to get query parameters in Angular 2 RC4

Tags: angular, typescript

How does one get query parameters in Angular 2 RC4? I tried the docs and they make no sense whatsoever.

e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/models/initials/mid_c1e1c31e6eff42f1982af4124a823b36?test=4
```

In `ngOnInit` how do I get the value of the parameter `test`?

```
private sub: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

        console.log(params);
        let id = params['test']; 
        console.log(id);

     });

}
```

This is how I navigate to the route where I want to get the query parms:

```
   this._router.navigate(['models/initials/'+model_id+'?test=4']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {}

 ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.map(params => params['test'])
            .subscribe(id => { /* do what you want with the id */ });
```

Comment: I get undefined when I do { /* do what you want with the id */ console.log(id) }

Comment: @Tampa can you debug and see what your route.params contains?

Comment: My url looks like what I posted. If I change to params['id'] I get mid_c1e1c31e6eff42f1982af4124a823b36 so that part works.  I just cant get the ?test=4.  Looking at that route.param object I dont see it there despite being in the URL window.

Comment: @Tampa is your route set up correctly to handle 2 parameters? IE: 'url/:id/:test' (or equivalent)?

Comment: The poster asked about **query** parameters not route nor path parameters... See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The OP asked about query parameters, the correct way to do this is to use the queryParams object off of the route.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params);
    let id = params['test']; 
    console.log(id);
 })
}
```

This is different than the params object which the other answers reference.

I'd also recommend using the NavigationExtras object to add to the query string correctly per: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html down in the "Query Parameters and Fragments" section.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ActivatedRoute:

```
private sub: Subscription;


constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      (param: any) => this.test = param['test']
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `RouteSegment`

```
 routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment) {
    this.userName = curr.getParam('userName');
    this.projId = curr.getParam('projId');
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

can be done in this way which uses Javascript :

```
(new URL(location)).searchParams.get("parameter_name")
```